# Outlook 2007 Duration Totalling

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How can you get the "Start", "End" and "Duration" field values in Outlook Calendar or Journal to total within Outlook or to export in numerical format so they can be totalled in Excel?  When I copy and paste into Excel the are in text format, which is not much use for time recording.